# Concrete example of a ripple effect in JJG's layers of user experience design?

Tags: ux-field, ux-designer, design-process, agile

In Jesse James Garrett's book *[The Elements of User Experience: User-centered Design for the Web and Beyond](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Elements_of_User_Experience_The.html?id=9QC6r5OzCpUC&redir_esc=y)*, there's a model consisting of 5 planes (`Strategy`, `Scope`, `Structure`, `Skeleton`, and `Surface`).

I know that the ripple effect means that changes on one of the planes will affect the others. But to be more specific, how would one describe the ripple effect on the Strategy level, for example, when you set out with a strategy and you end up later realizing your strategy would not work well, so you make changes to it. Of course, there are visible and invisible ripple effects.

**Based on Garrett's UI Model, what can a concrete example of ripple effect be?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Generally speaking

The diagram you reference sort of hints at the impact of change within itself.

[image: Jesse James Garrett's layers of experience design diagram]

As noted on the vertical continuum, the layers represent increasing levels of detail to solve a given problem. When there is a change at any level, the team needs to evaluate if that change fits within the given parameters.

Changes at the `Strategy` or `Scope` levels are more likely to have downstream impact than `Surface` or `Skeleton` going the other way. `Surface` has to deal with the finer points — a lot of little things may change without deviating from the preceding definitions.

## The specifics

Let's look at it from opposite ends of the spectrum. Here's an imaginary scenario:

> Our e-commerce site has great conversion, moderate average order value, but low penetration into the product mix. We believe that a strategic initiative to **improve product discovery** will increase items per order and average order value, and enhance customer experience and loyalty.

#### Change initiated at the `Surface` layer

The interface design team was asked to design a basic product recommendation component. During their prototyping, someone on the team came up with a more dynamic solution that expands the recommendations into an immersive browsing experience.

Users responded well in a quick guerrilla test and the idea was pushed all the way up to the `Scope` layer. `Strategy` remains unchanged, but the `Scope` needs to be expanded for this, which will subsequently impact `Structure` and `Skeleton`.

#### Change initiated at the `Strategy` layer

In the course of analyzing test data from some early visual prototypes of the `Surface` solution, it became clear that the `Strategy` was flawed.

Increased product discovery has lead to customer indecision, browsing fatigue, and the experience team anticipates a spike in cart abandonment. The `Strategy` will now shift to focus on an up-sell approach targeted at lower-priced options. Everything changes ...

Let there be ripples.

---

***In the interest of thoroughness ...***

We should also include JJG's original, [more complex diagram of the Elements of UX](http://www.jjg.net/elements/pdf/elements.pdf).

[image: Jesse James Garrett's Elements of UX diagram]

Comment: This is really, really, really interesting!

Comment: Yes, that one is indeed useful. What else can you share about the "ripple effect"? Thanks a lot sir.

Comment: I could go on all day ... what aspects of the idea are still foggy for you? Feel free to hit me up in a more chat-friendly format: https://twitter.com/plainclothes

Comment: plainclothes: I do not have twitter, I am very sorry. Hmm not sure, if Stackexchange has chat?

Comment: In case you didn't get a notification ... http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/389/ux-chat

Comment: You must have 20 reputation on The Stack Exchange Network to talk here. See the faq.

Comment: Ugh. Feel free to email me, if you'd like. [Check my profile page](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/21857/plainclothes).

Comment: I cannot send you e-mail, I cannot find your e-mail address?

Comment: Got it! Got it, Got!

Comment: I just sent you an e-mail.

Comment: I am available on hangouts on Google?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57929/discussion-between-brianna-violet-and-plainclothes).